# Is anything other than unset($_SESSION) needed for logout?

Tags: php, facebook, session

Is there any reason that unsetting the session wouldn't be enough for a logout? Is there some security reason more is needed?

I have a script that uses the facebook login (using PHP). But for some reason, using any of the following messes with the login for some reason. After being logged out using any of the codes below, when trying to login using facebook redirect it it forces you to push the button twice for it to recognize that a facebook session has been created.

```
if (isset( $_COOKIE[session_name()] )) {
    setcookie(session_name(), "", time() -3600, "/" );
}
$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
```

Comment: You want to logout or not? Your question is not clear for me (thats why down vote)

Comment: What's not clear? The codes listed above mess with the facebook login script. The only thing that doesn't mess with it is the unset($_SESSION). I need a way to logout that won't mess with the facebook login code.

Is unsetting the session enough for the logout? Or are those other codes needed? If so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
$params = array('next' => 'http://something.com/logout.php');
$logout = $facebook -> getLogoutUrl($params);
$_SESSION['logout'] = $logout;                                                  `
```